# Testing a custom PolicyViolationHandler in FluentSecurity

Tags: unit-testing, fluent-security

I have written a custom policy in FluentSecurity (implement `ISecurityPolicy`) and a corresponding PolicyViolationHandler by implementing `IPolicyViolationHandler`.  Everything is working perfectly with the policy and the handler, however I'm doing some back-filling by writing some unit tests to test my implementation of `IPolicyViolationHandler.Handle(PolicyViolationException exception)`.
*I know I'm doing it backwards writing the test after the implementation (admission to avoid flames).*

**My question is**:  Is there a way to generate a `PolicyViolationException` object as a mock that I can pass in for my test?  PolicyViolationException doesn't have any public constructors (so I can't new an object), nor an abstract base, or interface to mock against (using Moq).

I took a look through the API but didn't see anything to generate one.  I know I could do some reflection magic to get one, but wanted to check if I was missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In releases up to and including version 2.0-alpha4 this is not possible. However, this issue **will be resolved in the upcoming 2.0-beta1 release** of FluentSecurity where the constructor will be made public.

https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/commit/09e9b69ef5a297d242f8a813babbeebd47b54818

Thanks for bringing this to my attention!